# Python: How to retrieve table name and corresponding columns name from JSON schema in python

Tags: python, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jsonschema, snowflake-schema

Sample Schema:

```
{
"CLASS_A" :  {
      "type": "object",
       "properties": {
           "CLASS_B": {
             "type": "array",
             "items": {
                 "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                     "NAME1": {
                          "type":  "string",
                       },
                     "NAME2": {
                          "type":  "string",
                       },
                     "CLASS_C":  {
                          "type": "array",
                          "items": {
                              "type": "object",
                              "properties": {
                                   "NAME3": {
                                       "type":  "string",
                                    },
                                   "NAME4": {
                                       "type":  "string",
                                   },
                                   
                                },
                            },
                        },  
                    },  
                },
            },
        },
    },  
},
```

CLASS_B and CLASS_C are the table names and NAME1 and NAME2 are the column names of the table CLASS_B

I have a big JSON schema with around 600 tables....

I need to automatically retrieve table names and their corresponding columns in one place.

Comment: What have you tried and what was blocking you?

Comment: If you're looking for an existing library to do this, you're out of luck. You're going to have to write the code for this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First, you change it to a dictionary with command

```
import json
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Then you read it as a dictionary with:

```
data['CLASS_A']['properties']
...
```